# How to return a Json from a Sql Select Query and place it in a view [ASP.Net 6 MVC]

Tags: sql, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to find a row by Id and get details about it then convert the result into a Json and return it to a View.cshtml where it can be seen. For example I want to get all Subjects and Grades a student has got so far.

This is what i tried so far..

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Find(int id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Grades WHERE Student = @Id";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Note nota = new Note();
                                nota.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                nota.StudentId = reader.GetInt32(1);
                                nota.MaterieId = reader.GetInt32(2); //Subject
                                nota.NotaObtinuta = reader.GetInt32(3); //The grade he got at that subject
                                gradesList.Add(nota);
                            }
                        }
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                    return View("FindResults", Json(gradesList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Found my answer. Using Newtonsoft.Json framwork I can serialize the list into a Json string and pass it as a parameter to the view.

```
var JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gradesList);
ViewBag.JsonData = JsonData;
return View("JsonResult", JsonData);
```

After that in the view I can display it either by using @Model or @ViewBag.JsonData

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer.
Using Newtonsoft.Json framwork i can serialize the list into a Json string and pass it as a parameter to the view.

```
var JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gradesList);
                ViewBag.JsonData = JsonData;
                return View("JsonResult", JsonData);
```

After that in the view i can display it either by using @Model or @ViewBag.JsonData